# How to resolve outofmemory error in scala code while querying in cassandra table?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have millions of records in the cassandra table and want to get all partition keys columns values. I'm getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error. See my sample code.

```
 val rowKeyRdd: Array[CassandraRow] =
    sc.cassandraTable(keyspace, table).select("customer_id", "uniqueaddress").collect()

 val clientPartitionKeys = rowKeyRdd.map(x => ClientPartitionKey(
    x.getString("customer_id"), x.getString("uniqueaddress"))).toList

 val clientRdd: RDD[CassandraRow] =
    sc.parallelize(clientPartitionKeys).joinWithCassandraTable(keyspace, table)
      .where("eventtime >= ?", startDate)
      .where("eventtime <= ?", endDate)
      .map(x => x._2)

    clientRdd.cache()
```

my aim is fetch the all rows within the given daterange.
so I applied logic like this: first get all partition keys from table then get the all records between date range using list of partition keys.

but in this case I m getting following error during exevution the scala code:

```
 ERROR 2016-02-11 13:05:54 org.apache.spark.util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread task-result-getter-1
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$HandleTable.grow(ObjectInputStream.java:3476) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$HandleTable.assign(ObjectInputStream.java:3282) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1792) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1707) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1345) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:69) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar:1.4.2.2]
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:89) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar:1.4.2.2]
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DirectTaskResult.value(TaskResult.scala:95) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar:1.4.2.2]
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskResultGetter.scala:60) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar:1.4.2.2]
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:51) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar:1.4.2.2]
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:51) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar:1.4.2.2]
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1652) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar:1.4.2.2]
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2.run(TaskResultGetter.scala:50) [spark-core_2.10-1.4.2.2.jar:1.4.2.2]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
Exception in thread "task-result-getter-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Please suggest me any solution in above code.

Comment: Might seem like a silly question, but have you tried increasing the amount of heap space?

Comment: Cassandra is all about structuring your table to fit your query. Can you explain what you are trying to query and what you plan on doing with the data?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of addressing this in code, try increasing the heap space available to your application by passing `-Xmx8g` (or whatever amount of RAM you need) to your JVM launch config.

Comment: after increase heap size getting

         ERROR 2016-02-12 07:54:48 akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl: Uncaught fatal error from thread [sparkDriver-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-5] shutting down ActorSystem [sparkDriver]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded